# Поиск в MySQL: найти в базе значение и вернуть номер строки

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица в `MySQL` и переменная с текстом. Так вот вопрос: как в базе найти значение этой переменной так, чтобы вернулся номер строки?

Comment: с такой формулировкой только rtfm mysql_query. а дальше только со знанием структуры таблицы...

Comment: Можно примерчик если не сложно

Comment: примерчик чего??

Comment: `SELECT id FROM table WHERE variable = 'mytext'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Искать не точное соответствие по введенной фразе и соответствие по ее частям можно таким образом:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `product` 
WHERE 
  MATCH(`meta_desc`, `meta_keywords`) 
  AGAINST('*ful**nam*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

При таком запросе в результат попадут записи имеющие вхождения фрагментов слов ful и nam

Надо учесть, что при работе с MATCH запрещено использовать в качестве именно полей зарезервированные слова.

Comment: ? экранированные тоже??

Comment: вроде да, почитайте вот эту статью http://lifeexample.ru/razrabotka-i-optimizacia-saita/polnotekstovyiy-poisk-mysql.html

Comment: хм, странно, хотя всегда пользовался LIKE и проблем не испытывал... спасибо.

Comment: Like медленный, и требующий хорошей характеристики, тем более НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ поиск с помощью него не сделаешь